# conditionally loading route, only works for route which is on top : React-Router

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, mern

I have 2 absolute routes /admin and /createpost

if the user component is on top of the create post in react router ordering, it will work, and the admin route shows nothing and vice versa, I am using lazy load so the component is not even there is the user is not logged in. Is this expected behaviour or is it a bug in react router?

this is the code

```
                    {true ?
                    (
                        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingMessage />}>
                            <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
                        </Suspense>
                    )   :
                        <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminsOnly} />

                    }

                    {true ? (
                        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingMessage />}>
                            <Route exact path="/create" component={CreatePost} />
                        </Suspense>
                    ) :
                        <Route exact path="/create" component={VerifyEmail} />
                    }
```

Comment: where is a condition?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: if something is conditional then should contain condition - I don't see it here - can you point it out?

Comment: haha ah ok, yeah its a terinary operator, I am loading the first route and the second is for false, it will not run because I hardcoded true to run the first and wrapeed it (), I thought it was clear, in real case it will not be true but some sort of state, to be super clear, the route for admin is running only if it is above the terinary case of create and vice versa, I did a fix-around but I was still wondering why this is happening as such